# How does $3 \cdot \sin(3 \cdot \frac{\pi}{6})$ equal to $0.5$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have done the following calculation to find the slope of a secant line given two $x-$values, $\frac{\pi}{18}, \frac{\pi}{6}$ to the function: $g(x)=3 \cdot \sin(3x)$:

When $x=\frac{\pi}{18}$ then, using substitution and simplifying afterwards, $y=\frac{3}{2}$ but when I use the same method to calculate $y$ when $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$ I get this:

$$
g(x)=y=3 \cdot \sin(3x)=3 \cdot \sin(3 \cdot \frac{\pi}{6})=3 \cdot \sin(\frac{3\pi}{6})=3\cdot \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=3\cdot 1=3
$$

However, when I plug $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$ into GeoGebra as well as the function and read the $y$-value, it gives me $0.52$. Why is this and what have I done wrong?

**Here's a graph of what I am talking about:**

[image]

Comment: From the image, $g$ is not $3 \sin(3x)$ but $3 \sin x$.

Comment: Also, the values are rounded to two decimal places. For instance, $\pi/6$ became $0.52$ as $\pi/6 \approx 0.5235987756$.

Comment: I think the mistake is $\dfrac{\pi}{6}\ne0.17$ because $0.17=\dfrac{1}{6}$